# Node - Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, odbc

I am facing issue with Node.js.

I am receiving this error :

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
> throw err;
> ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/odbc.node' Require stack:
>
> - C:\node\api\node_modules\odbc\lib\odbc.js
> - C:\node\api\index.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
>   at Object. (C:\node\api\node_modules\odbc\lib\odbc.js:1:20)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'C:\node\api\node_modules\odbc\lib\odbc.js',
>   'C:\node\api\index.js'   ] }

Includes in my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var odbc = require('odbc');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();
```

My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "node-odbc": "^0.2.10",
    "odbc": "^2.2.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Can somebody help me out with this issue?

Thank you for your time,

Petr

Comment: did you try to install odbc again ?

Comment: Oh my god... im so dumb... i was looking for a lot of complicated solutions and i forgot about the simplest one... Thank you very much